# linkWithin widget for wordpress - how it can be positioned?

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know how to position a widget called linkWithin on the page? By default it's putting it below every post. I want to display it in the sidebar though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [LinkWithin FAQ](http://www.linkwithin.com/faq):

> **How can I customize the placement of the widget on my blog?**
>
> Modify your HTML template to add the
>   code below at the place where you want
>   the widget to appear:
>
> ```
> <div class="linkwithin_div"></div>
> ```

So you'd take that bit of HTML out of your posts template and move it either directly into your sidebar template or paste it into a sidebar widget within WordPress's admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much followed the Rick's instruction but I had to change the div class to `linkwithin_hook` in order to work.

If you want to know the class name, try to find the `var linkwithin_div_class` of your `LinkWithin` code. I hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and the only workaround I could find was to:

1. Deactivate the LinkWithin WordPress plugin
2. Visit [LinkWithin](http://www.linkwithin.com) and resubmit my site
3. Instead of choosing WordPress Manual Install for my Platform, I chose **Other**
4. Copy the script code LW gives you and place in your footer.php file, right above the wp_footer() php call
5. On my single and home page php templates, I used the div that Manzabar provided you in addition to the [LW script to change the text to something of my own](http://www.linkwithin.com/faq) (Step 5 on the FAQ page)

Hope that helps you out or anyone else!